# Show content based on location using PHP

Tags: php, geolocation, location

I am trying to show content based on user location. For example, show  if outside of the country, Australia.

I have been using the documentation from this link: http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/php

This is the code I have been using. It will always show the echo even when I change the location.

```
<?php
require_once('geoplugin.class.php');
$geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
// If we wanted to change the base currency, we would uncomment the following         line
// $geoplugin->currency = 'EUR';

$geoplugin->locate();

echo "Geolocation results for {$geoplugin->ip}: <br />\n".

"Country Name: {$geoplugin->countryName} <br />\n".
"Country Code: {$geoplugin->countryCode} <br />\n";

if ( $geoplugin->countryName != "Australia" ) {
//our visitor is not using the same currency as the base currency
echo "Show International Popup";
}
?>
```

Cheers

Comment: how do you change location to test this?

Comment: You're already echoing the country name above, is it different from `Australia`? Also @developerwjk either proxy or just fake the geoplugin results.

Comment: What is the result of `$geoplugin->countryName` when you change the location to outside Australia?

Comment: BTW, the geoplugin has me about 450km away from my real location

Comment: Don't forget, it's your ISP Location @Drakes ;-)

Comment: @Darren Perhaps, but my paid GeoIP service has me accurately.

Comment: Where's the fun in that then @Drakes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, If I was you, I'd go via the `countryCode` instead of the `countryName`. It's more "containable" in a sense.

```
if($geoplugin->countryCode !== "AU") {
    // load your selector
}
```

On another note, what does your `countryName`/`countryCode` show? Is anything present in either of the variables?

Make sure you have error reporting on, encase your calls are failing:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
display_errors(-1); // or use E_ALL
```